# Self hosted веб утилита для мониторинга сервера (SSH, Logs, system info)

Tags: linux, сервер, ssh, поиск-программ, мониторинг

Подскажите пожалуйста, ищу приложение/утилиту для мониторинга состояния серверов.
Чтобы это было не клауд решение, а можно было самому развернуть.
Что требуется от системы:

1. Мониторинг ресурсов сервера (память, диск, процессор)
2. SSH доступ прямо из веб админки
3. Мониторинг логов (чтобы можно было отправлять логи на сервер с различных приложений)

Есть различные варианты по отдельности, но хотелось бы найти одно решение, которое покроет эти задачи.

Comment: А зачем нужно одно решение, если есть различные варианты по отдельности?

Comment: the dude но это не вэб

Comment: в том то и дело что надо все отдельно ставить, хотелось бы в одном месте

Comment: Комбайны, которые умеют всё, умеют всё плохо. Кроме того, это нарушает Unix-way и снижает отказоустойчивость и масштабируемость. Рекомендую вам перестать хотеть это

Comment: я когда то такое писал, там было все (вот ssh доступ не допилили, но это дело такое). Ресурсы мониторились, алерты слалались. Даже антивирус можно было запустить...

Comment: nagios, zabbix... мониторинг железок, логов, сбор информации и уведомлялки ЕМНИП есть... про shell/ssh из админки правда не помню...